# C# Queue problem

Tags: c#, reference, queue

Suppose I have a class

```
XYNode
{
    protected int mX;
    protected int mY;
}
```

and a queue

```
Queue<XyNode> testQueue = new Queue<XYNode>();
```

I want to check if a node with that specific x and y coordinate is already in the queue.
The following obviously doesn't work :

```
testQueue.Contains(new XYNode(testX, testY))
```

because even if a node with those coordinates is in the queue, we're testing against a different XYNode object so it will always return false.

What's the right solution ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest way is to override `Equals` so that one `XYNode` knows whether it's equal to another `XYNode`. You should override `GetHashCode()` at the same time, and possibly also implement `IEquatable<XYNode>` to allow a strongly-typed equality comparison.

Alternatively, you could write an `IEqualityComparer<XYNode>` implementation to compare any two nodes and return whether or not they're the same - and then pass that into the call to the [appropriate overload of the `Contains` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb919359.aspx) defined in `Enumerable` (assuming you're using .NET 3.5).

Further things to consider:

- Could you use private fields instead of protected ones?
- Could your class be sealed?
- Could your class be immutable?
- Should your class perhaps be a struct instead? (Judgement call...)
- Should you overload the == and != operators?

Comment: pretty soon you're going to win stackoverflow.com

Comment: I think Jon is trying to get enough points to turn this site into "BufferOverflow.com"

Answer (score 5):

To illustrate Jon Skeet's ... original ... answer:

```
class XYNode {
    protected int mX;
    protected int mY;

    public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || this.GetType() != obj.GetType()) { return false; }

        XYNode otherNode = (XYNode)obj;
        return (this.mX == other.mX) && (this.mY == other.mY);
    }
}
```

This is a pretty simplistic solution. There are a lot of additional factors to consider, which Jon has already mentioned.

Comment: You need to specify override and the parameter should be an object.

Comment: One handy thing about making a class sealed is that you can just use as/is instead of calling `GetType()` - you don't need to worry about being given a subclass instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate with a `foreach` and check the `X` and `Y` of your `XYNode` on every element.